# Objecto undefined

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Estoy imprimiendo un objecto `dateImagen.boolean` y me sale un error que el `Cannot read property 'boolean' of undefined`, le hago `console.log(dateImagen)`, pero si me sale la informacion que es esta:

```
Object {boolean: true, result: Array(2), mensaje: "Hay imagen"}
```

pero al imprimirlo `{{dateImagen.boolean}}` me sale ese mensaje de que boolean es undefined y si lo imprimo `{{dateImagen}}` si me imprime todo saliendo así:

```
[Object, Object]
```

Le hise un `JSON.stringify(dateImagen)` y lo imprimo y me sale el objecto como es pero en string. Saben si estoy cometiendo algo mal?, estoy practicando ionic2 haciendo un proyecto personal. Muchas gracias, esto es el codigo que hago:

imagenes.ts

```
export interface Images{
  boolean: boolean,
  result: any,
  mensaje: string
}
```

contenidoImages.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Images } from '../../app/commons/imagenes';

import { contenidoServices } from '../../app/services/contenidos';

@Component({
  selector: 'contenido-images',
  templateUrl: 'contenidoImages.html'
})

export class contenidoImage{
  dateImagen:Images;
  @Input() id: number;

  constructor(private contenido: contenidoServices){        
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    let idContenido = this.id;
    let imagenesContenido = this.contenido.getContenidoImagenes(idContenido);

    imagenesContenido.subscribe((res)=>{

        let date = {
            boolean: (res == 2) ? false : true,
            result: res,
            mensaje: (res == 2) ? 'No hay imagen' : 'Hay imagen'
        }

        this.dateImagen = date;
        console.log(this.dateImagen);
     },(err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

contenidoImages.html

```
<div>
  {{dateImagen.boolean}}
</div>
```

Comment: En la consola, imprime de nuevo `dateImagen` y sobre el atributo `boolean` da click derecho y selecciona la opción: `copy property path`, luego, sobre tu `console.log(dateImage);` pega lo copiado. Quedaría algo así: **Esto es solo un ejemplo:** `console.log(dateImagen[0]boolean)`

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave hola, lo hice y me copia solo el atributo `.boolean`

Comment: Albert, imprime: `console.log(dateImagen.boolean)`

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave vale, lo hice y si me muestra el resultado del objecto, me sale `true`, pero no se porque no me lo detecta al colocarlo al html `{{dateImagen.boolean}}`

Comment: has tratado de usar un `typeof(aqui el tipo de dato)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trate lo siguiente:

```
<div>
  {{dateImagen?.boolean}}
</div>
```

notese el uso de `?` elvis operator.

Usted tiene y hace uso de esto `{{dateImagen.boolean}}` en la vista pero existe un momento hasta que se complete la subcripcion, en la cual es nulo.

Especificando un `?` entre el objeto y la propiedad `{{dateImagen?.boolean}}` se asegura que se define antes de evaluar la union, *podrian entenderse como una navegacion segura*.

Cuando este valor resuelve la union sera actualizado por el control de cambios de Angular.

P.D: *No he probado su codigo pero segun su error y lo que comenta es posible que lo que se menciona en esta respuesta sea lo que busque.*

Comment: Muchas gracisa, funciona con `{{dateImagen?.boolean}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa:

```
console.log(dateImagen.boolean);
```

De todas maneras, te recomiendo que antes de usar el objeto `dateImagen` verifica siempre que el objeto no sea `NULL` o `undefined`.

Ejemplo:

```
// Solo se mostrará información si el objeto no es NULL o undefined:
if (dateImagen != null || dateImagen != undefined) {    
    console.log(dateImagen.boolean);
}
```

Comment: si, en la consola me sale el resultado pero porque al imprimirlo en html `{{dateImagen.boolean}}` me sale un error que no existe .boolean

Comment: @AlbertArias, antes de usar el .boolean, comprueba si efectivamente es un objeto. La verdad no conozco de AngularJS, pero debo suponer que el algún punto estás manipulando el objeto antes de que esté disponible para su uso en el div. Te recomiendo actualizar tu pregunta con la explicación de qué estás haciendo en: `export class contenidoImage...`